# Why is the extraction operator not working?

Tags: c++

I trying out some problems in Google's Code Jam. For the question [Store Credit](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=351101#), I have the following code in C++:

```
    if (input.is_open()) {
    getline(input, line);
    ss << line;
    ss >> nCases;

    for (int i = 0; i < nCases; i++) {
        getline(input, line);
        ss << line;
        ss >> credit;
        cout << credit << endl;

        getline(input, line);
        ss << line;
        ss >> nItems;
        cout << nItems << endl;
        int list[nItems];
    }
```

`input` is text file (everything has been correctly initialised), `line` is a string variable to hold the newly extracted line from the text file, while `ss` is a stringstream. `nCases`, `credit`, and `nItems` are just int variables. What got me confused is how the extraction operator works as expected when I'm getting `nCases` but stopped working once I'm trying to retrieve the value for `credit` and `nItems`.

Comment: Please describe in more detail: "works as expected", "stopped working", separators and data types.

Comment: By "work as expected", it means that the number in `ss` got extracted into the int variable, and "stopped working" means that the numbers failed to get extracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `ss << line;`, reset the stream with `ss.str(line); ss.clear();`

Answer (score 1):

if these are just integers per line then why not use `atoi`

```
if (input.is_open()) {
    getline(input, line);
    nCases = atoi( line.c_str() );

    for (int i = 0; i < nCases; i++) {
        getline(input, line);
        credit = atoi( line.c_str() );
        cout << credit << endl;

        getline(input, line);
        nItems = atoi( line.c_str() );
        cout << nItems << endl;
        int list[nItems];
    }
```

Comment: you need to add the header `<cstdlib>` in your source in order to use this standard library function